# About the characteristic equation of a square matrix (Cayley-Hamilton theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

Take, for example, $A$  of order $2 \times 2$. The characteristic equation comes to be $$A^2 - (\text{tr}(A)) A + \det (A) = 0 $$ But is this the only quadratic equation that this matrix satisfies? Can it satisfy infinitely many cubic and biquadratic equation?

Are the results the same for $3 \times 3$ matrices? That is, it satisfies only one cubic equation that is its characteristic equation, satisfy infinite biquadratic equations and may or may not satisfy even one quadratic equation?

What can be said about general $n \times n$ matrices?

Any help (even partial) and even links are appreciated. Thank you for the help. I cannot show my work because I have no idea of how to solve this, sorry.

---

I have proved that the only quadratic a $2 \times 2$ is its characteristic equation by assuming a general $2\times 2$ matrix and assuming the equation to $A^2 - XA + Y (I) = 0$ , then solving for $X$ and $Y$.Assume that A is not a null matrix.

Comment: If $f(A)=0$ for a polynomial $f$, then $(g\cdot f)(A)=0$ for every polynomial $g$ as well.

Comment: For every square matrix $A$, there is a polynomial $f(x)$ with minimum degree possible that $f(A)=0$. The set of polynomials with the property $P(A)=0$ form an ideal with the unique, monic (=coefficient of maximum degree equals 1) minimal polynomial $f(x)$ as the generator. In other words every polynomial for which $P(A)=0$ has the $f(x)$ as a divisor. Characteristic polynomial is no exception. Indeed one of the ways to find the minimal polynomial of a matrix, is to apply the factors of characteristic polynomial on a complete basis and taking greatest common divisor. working on finding a link.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the proof?

Comment: Please read (Wolfram definition of minimal polynomial)<http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMinimalPolynomial.html> and three references therein are useful. I read Linear algebra by Hoffman and Kunze, chapters 4,5,6 discuss this topic but Dummit and Foote is more popular. I searched it and through the immediate results, this document is good for a brief intro (brief-ref)<http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~mmertens/MinimalPolynomial.pdf>

Comment: Awww, now I remember, a very awesome book to understand these topics very easily and very thoroughly with nice examples is "Comprehensive Introduction to Linear Algebra - PART II - POLYNOMIALS AND CANONICAL FORMS" by Joel G. Broida and S. Gill Williamson. You can find an online version here <https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gill/CILASite/>, study chapter 7 on minimal and characteristic polynomial. This book is crazy awesome.

Comment: If you have learnt about minimal polynomials, the answer should be clear: when $m\ge2$, there are infinitely many **monic** degree-$m$ polynomials $p$ such that $p(A)=0$ if and only if the minimal polynomial of $A$ has degree $<m$ and the underlying field is infinite.

Comment: I m studying the link provided by kk Mcdonald , can anyone tell me about remark 1.5 in the pdf.Don't know what that means and is the minimal polynomial unique? @K.K.McDonald

Comment: @aryanbansal The only important thing to take from remark 1.5 is that the eigenspace of $A$ associated with $\lambda$ is a subspace.  The minimal polynomial (if it is defined to have a leading coefficient of $1$, which it usually is) is unique.